# Debugging JavaScript code in iOS simulator using Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, safari, web-inspector

I am building an iOS app in which I have a webView i.e. UIWebView not WkWebView and I have some JavaScript code that uses AngularJS for UI manipulation.

I run my app in the iOS simulator from Xcode and then open Safari and go to Develop -> iOS Simulator -> AppName -> index.html, which attaches the safari web inspector to the web view. In the inspector under the resources tab I select the relevant JavaScript file and put a breakpoint for the JavaScript code that I want to start from.

What happens now is when I navigate to the part of my app when the JavaScript code is executed, it pauses in the web inspector just fine. The problem is, I cannot navigate through the code: it just freezes. I cannot unpause it.

What I do notice in my Xcode console is this error

> Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...

This doesn't happen all the time, just 60-70% of the time when I am working on my app. So this is my first iOS app and I am building it using Swift.
This seems like I have a missing link somewhere. But any tips or anything would be great.

Comment: Out of interest, did you get to the bottom of this problem?

Comment: No not really, I honestly still do not know what the problem was. However, I think I noticed a certain trend i.e. when there are errors in the JS code the debugger would crash? I know that pretty much defeats the purpose of debugging. Anyway for the most part I resorted to old school debugging i.e. I put print statements in my Javascript code which I would then have a look at in the debugger